# How to open a "collapse" menu automatically?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have a site with the Bootstrap 4 theme. I want the `collapseMenuManage` menu to automatically open when it is presented. Here is the HTML code for my page :

```
<div id="modal_aside_first" class="modal fixed-right pl-0 fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-aside" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="accordion list-group mb-0" id="accordionMenu">

          <div id="headingMenuMain">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 pl-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMenuMain" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseMenuMain">
              <i class="bi bi-plus-circle bi-lg"></i> Menu principal
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseMenuMain" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingMenuMain" data-parent="#accordionMenu">
            ...
          </div>

          <div id="headingMenuManage">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 pl-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMenuManage" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenuManage">
              <i class="bi bi-plus-circle bi-lg"></i> Gérer votre compte
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseMenuManage" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingMenuManage" data-parent="#accordionMenu">
            ...
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tested this JS code, but it doesn't work :

```
  $('#modal_aside_first').on('.collapse', function () { 
    $(this).find("#collapseMenuManage .collapse").collapse("toggle");
  });
```

Comment: Why would that work?

Comment: `.collapse` is not an event

Comment: @GetSet What should I put in my JS file for it to work ?

Comment: add class maybe. I dont really know. Will upvote you tho so this gets attention.

Comment: You have two divs with Id `headingMenuManage`. Which do you want to open?

Comment: @codemonkey I want to open the accordion of the headingMenuManage

Comment: Your accordion will be open by default anyway when you load the page. In order for it to be closed, you have to give it class 'collapse'. So if it's open by default and you want it to be open on page load, what are you trying to accomplish? I don't get it.

Comment: I updated the code because I made a mistake

Comment: Now your code is inside a modal. So are you saying that you want the accordion to unfold when the modal pulls up?

Comment: @codemonkey The headingMenuManage menu only appears on certain page. It should be opened automatically when present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `on` function is used to handle an event and `.collapse` is a CSS selector, not and event. The correct event is `show.bs.modal` as [explained here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#events). Secondly, the correct CSS selector is `"#collapseMenuManage"`...

```
$('#modal_aside_first').on('show.bs.modal', function () { 
  $(this).find("#collapseMenuManage").collapse("toggle");
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/6kcLUNtMlv)

Comment: It's perfect, thank you. I have a little problem. I have 2 menu in the same `headingMenuMain` and `headingMenuManage` arccordion. The `headingMenuMain` menu is open by default, I want to close it when `headingMenuManage` is present. Currently, both menus are open. Normally in my accordion only one menu can be opened at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but in bootstrap 4 you can use `class="collapse show"` to show content automatically.

Example:

```
  <div class="card">
<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </button>
  </h5>
</div>

<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
  </div>
</div>
```

More details you can see in bootstrap 4 docs [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to do want to do this with JS.

Comment: @mlllmmlml ahhh ok sorry! I misunderstood you... :)